# Express not using correct root for ect.js

Tags: node.js, express, ectjs

I've thrown together a quick express.js app and am trying to get [ect](http://ectjs.com/) working with it. However, no matter what I try, express keeps trying to files in the wrong location. I've followed the instructions given on the home page (and [git](https://github.com/baryshev/ect)) to the letter.

My `server.js`:

```
import express from 'express';
import path from 'path';
import ECT from 'ect';

const port = 3000;
const app = express();

const renderer = ECT({
  watch: true,
  root: __dirname + '/src',
  ext: '.html'
});
app.set('view engine', 'ect');
app.engine('ect', renderer.render);

console.log(renderer.render('index'));

app.listen(port, function(error) {
  if (error) {
    console.log(error);
  } else {
    console.log("Listening on port " + port + "...");
  }
});

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.render('index');
});
```

The `console.log` prints out the correct file from the correct location. However, trying to access `/` in a browser results in a:

```
Error: Failed to lookup view "src/index" in views directory "/home/david/taekwondo2/views"
    at Function.render (/home/david/taekwondo2/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:10:10)
...
```

As an aside, I also have the `node-sass-middleware` installed.

Why isn't express playing fair?

Answer (score 0):

hello dear friend i think you just made a little mistake , as i saw the readme file i found something i think you should fix it like this :

like the readme : [this link here](https://github.com/baryshev/ect)

```
import express from 'express';
import path from 'path';
import ECT from 'ect';

const port = 3000;
const app = express();

const renderer = ECT({
  watch: true,
  root: __dirname + '/src',
  ext: '.ect' // <== this must be same as your template engine format (.ect)
});
app.set('view engine', 'ect');
app.engine('ect', renderer.render);

console.log(renderer.render('index'));

app.listen(port, function(error) {
  if (error) {
    console.log(error);
  } else {
    console.log("Listening on port " + port + "...");
  }
});

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.render('src/index');
});
```

Comment: This makes no difference. Leaving it blank also does not fix the issue. express is still trying to read the files from `view`. Also, I had made a a small mistake copying my supplied code into my question (I had an extra `src` in the `res.render`); I've removed that.